# How to scroll a div, pause & restart in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I make a simple javascript animation to scroll a div (#MyDiv) from say 300px to - 300px over 15 seconds, pause for 15 seconds, then replay, and keep doing this on an endless loop?

I tried with css using multiple methods but its just not smooth enough for my needs.

Comment: After the 15-second pause, do you want the element to go back down again (`-300px` to `300px`) in 15 seconds followed by another 15-second pause before doing it all again in an endless loop?

Comment: I should have been more clear: 300px left scrolls to -300pxleft (so scrolls from right to left), pause, then repeats i.e starts from 300px left again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that CSS3 animations are almost always more smooth than animations done by Javascript libraries.

Here's a way to do it without any Javascript, with CSS3 animations:

```
#scrollingContent
{
    animation: scroll 30s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -webkit-animation: scroll 30s linear 0s infinite normal;
}
@keyframes scroll
{
    0% { top: 300px; }
    50% { top: -300px; }
    100% { top: -300px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll
{
    0% { top: 300px; }
    50% { top: -300px; }
    100% { top: -300px; }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nj9yfk7b/

And here's an alternative way to do it with native Javascript and CSS3 transitions:

Working demo and code: http://jsfiddle.net/yfk7330j/
In this case, the transitions are triggered by Javascript by setting and un-setting a certain class name on the element that should be scrolling.

The *transition* version allows for better control with Javascript, while the *animation* version just does it's looping thing infinitely.

I tried to keep the code clean as possible, but please let me know if it needs any clarification.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, I'm working on a mobile (iPhone) widget and have tried many css methods including yours, I also tried @-webkit-keyframes scroll {
 0% {-webkit-transform: translate3d(320px, 0px, 0px);}
 100% {-webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px, 0px, 0px);}  
} but none of them are smooth! I thought I would try js.

Comment: That's very interesting. I do a lot of mobile web development also, and for me CSS3 transitions have always been more smooth than Javascript animations. Especially -webkit-transform is surprisingly smooth on older iPhones (as I suspect Safari uses Core Animation for that - not sure though). I do see your point though; at this speed it does run a bit (just tested on iPhone 4), but with `-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 300px)` it's very smooth for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nj9yfk7b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the functions ScrollBy and SetInterval can help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

You can use the intervals to jump every x ms y pixels, and then wait 15 seconds after you have reached an amount of pixels.

Also, I've seen this JQuery plugin, maybe it can also help (though I haven't researched it properly though):

[Scrolld.js](http://scrolldjs.com)

Rememberer that people here won't write the code for you, but will happily help you pass through specific problems.

Comment: Thanks, the set interval will help but the scroll by isn't a smooth scroll, Iv'e seen codes on the net where they set it to repeat every 20ms or so to get it smooth but they are always for some function that I don't need nor understand & I don't know how to strip out the part I need, ah well, another day on the net tomorrow trying to suss it out.